# Google Daydream controller (hardware) on Nexus 6p

Tags: android, daydream, nexus-6p

I feel insulted!

Just got Google's Daydream headset, connected controller to my **Nexus 6p**, ran my own game and NOTHING!

I used another phone to emulate the controller. Now I have actual controller, but it doesn't work because google doesn't support my phone.

I can't download the **Daydream app** which seems to be the only source to manage the controller. I'm looking for solution how to hack around. Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple solutions:

1. change your phone internal settings to be recognised as Pixel phone, so play.store will allow you to download daydream app (requires root)
2. install custom Pixel rom (messy)
3. **download daydream.apk** file from the mirror source -- works like a charm! I used apkmirror.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is someone who got it working.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/5c6jm1/so_ive_managed_to_get_daydream_working_guide/

All you need is the daydream apk and the vr keyboard apk.

I am not sure about google's TOS and what not so if you go that route I don't know if it is officially allowed.

Google does state that the nexus 6p is not daydream ready. That being said I'm planning on using one as well.

From what I have read online though, performance will not be very good.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it's important to post the critical information in the answer itself (and provide the link for reference).  Reason being, if that link should be unreachable or deleted entirely, the answer becomes meaningless to others who need it later.

Comment: I know how to emulate controller using another phone. But I have actual controller google made. I want to get it working